How to make the ( cube sphere maping ) as single mesh in Unity c#
What i mean is when using (cube  sphere maping ) we use 6 planes and normalize it to get the sphere ,
but that not change that the sphere is 6 saperated meshes , so when i try to change the vertices postion with brush tool in unity i got the faces saparated . what i want is a way to get the verteces without duplicates and the boundary of the faces stitched and trianglated . and thanks anyway.
Here The code im using if anyone cares ( Ai generated code).
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int resolution = 10;  // Resolution for each face of the cube
    public float radius = 1f;    // Radius of the sphere

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateCubeSphere();
    }

    void GenerateCubeSphere()
    {
        MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.name = "CubeSphere";

        // Create the cube vertices and triangles
        List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        List<int> triangles = new List<int>();

        // Generate the 6 faces of the cube
        CreateFace(Vector3.up, vertices, triangles);    // Top
        CreateFace(Vector3.down, vertices, triangles);  // Bottom
        CreateFace(Vector3.left, vertices, triangles);  // Left
        CreateFace(Vector3.right, vertices, triangles); // Right
        CreateFace(Vector3.forward, vertices, triangles); // Front
        CreateFace(Vector3.back, vertices, triangles);    // Back

        // Normalize the vertices to form a sphere
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = vertices[i].normalized * radius;
        }

        // Assign the vertices and triangles to the mesh
        mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();  // For smooth shading

        // Assign the generated mesh to the MeshFilter
        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
    }

    // Function to create one face of the cube
    void CreateFace(Vector3 normal, List<Vector3> vertices, List<int> triangles)
    {
        // Determine the axes for the face
        Vector3 axisA = new Vector3(normal.y, normal.z, normal.x); // Axis orthogonal to the face normal
        Vector3 axisB = Vector3.Cross(normal, axisA);

        // Create a grid for this face
        int vertexIndexStart = vertices.Count;
        for (int y = 0; y <= resolution; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= resolution; x++)
            {
                // Determine the position of the vertex on the unit cube
                Vector2 percent = new Vector2(x, y) / resolution;
                Vector3 pointOnCube = normal + (percent.x - 0.5f) * 2f * axisA + (percent.y - 0.5f) * 2f * axisB;
                vertices.Add(pointOnCube);
            }
        }

        // Create triangles for the face (correct winding order)
        for (int y = 0; y < resolution; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < resolution; x++)
            {
                int i = vertexIndexStart + x + y * (resolution + 1);

                // Inverted normals fix: Swapping the order of vertices for correct winding
                triangles.Add(i);
                triangles.Add(i + 1);
                triangles.Add(i + resolution + 1);

                triangles.Add(i + resolution + 1);
                triangles.Add(i + 1);
                triangles.Add(i + resolution + 2);
            }
        }
    }

}


